# Code to detect back slash character in a string using regex is not working?

Tags: java, regex

Hi I am having a regular expression which tries to check the presence of a set of characters including back slash \ . However it works for most characters in the character set except for back slash . Any idea what is wrong.

Here is my code snippet.

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
public class Testing {  
    public static void main(String args[]) {        
       String checkCharactersRegex = "[a-zA-Z!\"£$%&*@\\-_=~#':;,<.>/?|']";
       Pattern pattern1 = Pattern.compile(checkCharactersRegex);
       List<String> msisdns = new ArrayList<>();
       msisdns.add("(089) \\ 636 48018");
       msisdns.forEach( val ->  System.out.println(pattern1.matcher(val).find()) );
    }

}
```

Output if you execute above is

```
false
```

I would expect it to be true . Appreciate any help

thank you

Comment: In java source, `\\-` escapes the hyphen (`-`). To escape the back slash, use four backslashes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use backslash as a literal, you have to type `\\\\` as `\` is also an escape character in regular expressions.

Answer (score 2):

Use below code:

```
String checkCharactersRegex = "[a-zA-Z!\"£$%&*@\\\\-_=~#':;,<.>/?|']";
```

Result https://ideone.com/6AeLiE